# Azure Durable Functions invoked in mixed slots

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Function App containing 2 deployment slots:

- S1 - production slot
- S2 - testing slot

Function App contains 3 functions:

- F3 - webhook function, waits for response from internet
- F2 - calls an external service via internet / HTTP
- F1 (the orchestrator) - invokes F3 and F2 with context

F1 is exposed over internet and can be invoked via HTTP request.

---

When I invoke F1 from S1, there are cases when it invokes F2 of S2 instead of S1, or F3 of S2 instead of S1.

Assuming no coding error, what could be the reason a function from S1 invoke the function of S2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using the same storage account for both the slots and the same task hub name as well. This is why the other function app is picking up tasks from the other.

You could either have separate storage accounts using [deployment settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#create-a-deployment-setting) or [set a different task hub name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp#multiple-function-apps) for each.